# How to re-initialise data-sort on jQuery DataTables?

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using jQuery Datatables in my project and I have made "custom value" sorting available on a column by using the attribute `data-sort` as described here:
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html

Works fine. But now I am using Javascript/jQuery to update the values of these attributes, and the dataTable doesn't take into account the new values, it still sorts using the original values.

Update is done on the attribute directly as such:

```
$('td#myColumnId').attr('data-order', newValue);
```

How can I force my dataTable to re-initialise my custom sort values?

So far I have tried `.draw()` and `.dataTable()` but unfortunately that is not working.

I'm looking forward to a possible solution.

Comment: You have to destroy you Datatable first and then redraw

Comment: "_I am using Javascript/jQuery to update the values of these attributes_" - how do you do that, please provide a code example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [**`invalidate()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().invalidate()) the cell(s). dataTables have no chance to know that you programmatically have changed orthogonal data (=the custom sort values) for one or more cells in a column. If you have an instance like

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
```

and change `data-order` by

```
$('td#myColumnId').attr('data-order', newValue);
```

then `invalidate` the cell / column by

```
table.cells("#myColumnId").invalidate();
```

Comment: It wouldn't work because `data-` attributes are read upon initialization, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf8tad7f/) for demonstration where sorting order doesn't change even after `invalidate()`. As a side note, there is a [bug #643](https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/643) in DataTables with `invalidate()` function that has only been fixed in [nightly build](https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js).

Comment: @Gyrocode.com - well, I guess **http://jsfiddle.net/668obv2a/** must be some kind of magic then :) That fiddle is my own personal proof of concept from yesterday, before answering.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com The problem with your fiddle is that `cell().invalidate()` not is supported - but `cells().invalidate()` is, and works - thats why I used `cells()` in the answer above.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not supported, see [`cell().invalidate()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell%28%29.invalidate%28%29). Strange, but your fiddle works, weird. Even if I change it to `cell().invalidate()`, it also work but not my demo. Let me see what's the problem.

Comment: You're right, it works fine, even with `cell.invalidate()`, see [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kf8tad7f/2/). Great answer!

Comment: Thanks guys, this worked! `.invalidate()` threw an error for me earlier (dataTables version 1.10.7), but Gyrocodes comment on the nightly build pointed me in the direction of updating to  the (current) latest version 1.10.9. That in combination with `.invalidate` has it working perfectly.